# Parse fetching objects from a few classes returns 0 (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch objects from a few classes at the same time, but all of them except 1 returning 0 objects.
I really don't know what to do.

My code:

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Dogs"];
query.limit=1000;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.dogs=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Cats"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }

    self.cats=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Mice"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.mice=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Elephants"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.elephants=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Lions"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.lions=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];
```

Does anybody have an idea why is it?

Thank you!

Comment: What's in the data store? What is different between the bits that work and don't? Is the result always the same? What about if you change the order or comment some out?

Comment: @Wain They're all the same. PFObject with NSString column

Answer (score 0):

you should use different references for PFQuery - -

```
PFQuery *query1=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Dogs"];
query1.limit=1000;
[query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.dogs=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

PFQuery query2=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Cats"];
[query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }

    self.cats=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

PFQuery query3=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Mice"];
[query3 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.mice=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

PFQuery query4=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Elephants"];
[query4 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.elephants=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];

PFQuery query5=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Lions"];
[query5 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error description]);
    }
    self.lions=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
}];
```

Comment: This would be quite surprising if true.  Have you produced a demonstration of this working, but not working when the same stack variable is reused?